# How to fix /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--daemonize'

Tags: service, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

After uograding, mariadb is not starting on Ubuntu 18.04

The log file says

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--daemonize'
```

Starting /usr/sbin/mysqld on the command line works

I am on version 10.1.41

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.41-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike MySQL, the `--daemonize` option in MariaDB is not supported.
So it looks like, that MySQL was replaced by MariaDB, but the configuration file was not updated properly.
Try to remove the daemonize option in /etc/systemd/system/mysql*.service configuration files.

Comment: And file a bug report with Ubuntu?